# How do I remove Ubuntu dual-booted with Windows 7?

Tags: 12.10, dual-boot, windows-7, uninstall

I want to uninstall Ubuntu 12.10. I installed Ubuntu (from a usb/cd) using the option "Install along with Windows 7". Windows 7 is installed as usual in C:\ and Ubuntu is installed in some other drive.

How do I uninstall Ubuntu from this setup?

Answer (score 1):

Well, you must first fix your `MBR` so that windows7 boot loader can act. in order to do that there is a nice tool in [HirenCD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd) named `Fix MBR`. Try to download it and use it. Then you must format your Ubuntu partition with any tools you know. There are also some partitioning tools in that CD, I recommend `Paragon partition manager` ;)

Answer (score 0):

Back everything up, and then just delete the linux partition(s) using Disk Management. After that, load a Windows CD, or [HBCD](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd), and repair the Master Boot Record. Finally, you can reclaim the space for Windows, also using Disk Management.